# JSON to HTML Table JavaScript Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

## JSON to HTML Table JavaScript Not Working

I've written this function to display the contents of the JSON file in an HTML table. However, it's returning as `undefined`.

I don't seem to be able to work out why this is happening. The console log displays the data just fine, but not the HTML table.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the way `arrays` are parsed?

I want to keep the code short and clean, but wondering if there is a better way to do this without the `undefined` error. Maybe Vanilla JavaScript is better, using `fetch`?

Live page is found here: [LBRYnomics](https://lbry.social/lbrynomics)

Thanks in advance!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {     $.getJSON('https://www.brendonbrewer.com/lbrynomics/subscriber_counts.json', function(data) {
    var humanTimeSub = `${data.human_time_utc}`
    $(".human-time-sub").html(humanTimeSub)
    var sub_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      sub_data += '<tr>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + value.ranks + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + value.vanity_names + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + value.claim_ids + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + value.subscribers + '</td>';
      sub_data += '</tr>';
      console.log(key + '=' + value);
    });
    $('#sub-stats').append(sub_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sub-stats">
  <tr>
    <th>RANK</th>
    <th>VANITY NAME</th>
    <th>CLAIM ID</th>
    <th>SUBS</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Each of those properties `ranks` & `vanity_names` & `claim_ids` etc are individual arrays and are properties of `data` object itself. You are misinterpreting the data structure received. Do you control the api data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple different arrays for each of those properties.

Assuming they are all in same relationship order you can loop over one of the arrays and use the iteration index to access corresponding elements from each of the other arrays.

Something like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {     $.getJSON('https://www.brendonbrewer.com/lbrynomics/subscriber_counts.json', function(data) {
    var humanTimeSub = `${data.human_time_utc}`
    $(".human-time-sub").html(humanTimeSub);        
    
    var sub_data = '';
    $.each(data.ranks, function(i, rank) {
      sub_data += '<tr>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + rank + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + data.vanity_names[i] + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + data.claim_ids[i] + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + data.subscribers[i] + '</td>';
      sub_data += '</tr>';
      //console.log(key + '=' + value);
    });
    $('#sub-stats').append(sub_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sub-stats">
  <tr>
    <th>RANK</th>
    <th>VANITY NAME</th>
    <th>CLAIM ID</th>
    <th>SUBS</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly and it's just a small amendment. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think after inspecting the api it looks the items are put in different array with no connection but they have the same length. So assuming that attrbute1 at index N maps to attribute2 at index N and so on.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {     $.getJSON('https://www.brendonbrewer.com/lbrynomics/subscriber_counts.json', function(data) {
    var humanTimeSub = `${data.human_time_utc}`
    $(".human-time-sub").html(humanTimeSub)
    var sub_data = '';
    for(var i=0; i<data.ranks.length; i++){
    //$.each(data.ranks, function(key, value) {
      sub_data += '<tr>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + data.ranks[i] + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + data.vanity_names[i] + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + data.claim_ids[i] + '</td>';
      sub_data += '<td>' + data.subscribers[i] + '</td>';
      sub_data += '</tr>';
      //console.log(key + '=' + value);
    //});
    }
    $('#sub-stats').append(sub_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sub-stats">
  <tr>
    <th>RANK</th>
    <th>VANITY NAME</th>
    <th>CLAIM ID</th>
    <th>SUBS</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if I needed the extra `for` statement, so chose the other answer because it was smaller/cleaner. Many thanks for your help also.